# Can I tell what version of Visual Studio was used to build a DLL by examining the DLL itself

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, winapi, dll

I need to rebuild a DLL that was last built years ago. I have original C source code, but not the Visual Studio project or solution. I would like to try to rebuild it, using the same Visual Studio version that was used originally. I can tell that this is a plain old Windows DLL, not .NET. I also know that the source code is in C. Is there anything else I can tell about the original build environment and tools by examining the DLL binary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Sure, this is totally possible. The key is that all PE-format images (the Windows format for executable binaries, including DLLs and EXEs) have headers that contain attributes and other information about the binary itself. Microsoft's toolchain always sets fields in that header that indicate the version of the tools used to build it. So you can just dump that header and examine those fields to find out what you want to know.

While there are third-party applications that can extract and pretty-print this information for you, the easiest way to get at it if you have any version of Visual Studio or the Windows SDK installed is dumpbin. Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt, type `dumpbin /headers <path to your DLL>`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll get a big list of header data; don't let it intimidate you, you're only interested in a couple of fields.

Scroll up to the top. For a DLL, you'll see that the file type is a DLL (obviously). The first property in the "FILE HEADER VALUES" section is also sometimes interesting: it tells you whether the DLL is for a 32-bit or 64-bit machine. Then look under the next section, "OPTIONAL LINKER VALUES", for the "linker version" field. This, as I mentioned, is filled in by all Microsoft linkers with the version of the linker used to create the binary. The format is major.minor, so 14.00 is Visual Studio 2015, 10.00 is Visual Studio 2010, etc. There's [a table of these version numbers on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History) (the column you want is labeled "Version Number" here, since you want the version of the *linker*, not the version of the compiler, cl.exe). Other potentially interesting fields here are the "operating system version" and/or "subsystem version"—these will tell you which version of Windows that the binary was built to target. For example, 10.00 means Windows 10, 5.01 means Windows XP, and so on. Again, see [Wikipedia for a table of Windows version numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions).

Another relevant piece of information might be which version of the C runtime library (CRT) that your binary links (assuming that it does, in fact, link to the CRT). You can determine this using dumpbin as well, but this time looking at the imports. (Or you can use something like [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to get a pretty-printed listing.) Run `dumpbin /imports <path to your DLL>`, and then scroll through the list looking for something that begins with "MSVCR". The rest of the name indicates the version number. MSVCR80 means VC++ 8, or VS 2005. MSVCR90 means VC 9, or VS 2008. MSVCR100 means VC 10, or VS 2010. And so on.

All of this works even if symbols have been stripped from the binary.

Comment: Thank you, Cody.
I got linker version 9.0, operating system version 5.00 and subsystem version 5.00. Looks like Visual Studio 2008.
Under imports I see multiple functions imported from KERNEL32.dll, but nothing else. Does it necessarily mean that C runtime was linked statically? Or is it possible, the DLL does not need C runtime at all, even through it was written in C? It seems like it should be possible to tell whether C runtime was statically included in the DLL, right?

Comment: @George - but you have src code - so can easy view are crt used. and not mandatory use the same version of VS - this is only shell. really compilation/link process depended from cl.exe/link.exe version but in general it back compatible - old code usual compiled with newer CL, but very possible many new warnings. the main your problem can be with crt if it used - you may be need old crt headers/libs. if not crt - faster of all you can build in any VS, with any cl/link

Comment: Thanks you to both of you. It builds and works now with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Quick update on this, that interpretation of the VS version table on that wiki doesn't quite match Cody's answer in 2017 and beyond.  In VS 2017 VS IDE version is 15.x.x, however the VC++ toolset versions (there is actually more than one now) is either 14.11 or 14.12 depending on the update, <=15.4 and >15.4, respectively, as of today.  The linker version you'll obtain from PE headers will match the VC++ toolset versions, not VS versions.

Comment: Here is a more accurate table: http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2015/08/12/version-history-of-vc-mfc-and-atl/

Comment: _"the column you want is labeled 'Version Number' here, since you want the version of the linker, not the version of the compiler, cl.exe"_ I'm a little confused by this. There's only one column labeled "Version Number" - why does this column apply only to the linker and, if so, which column gives the compiler's version number? Without context that seems to be a non sequitur!

Comment: @Cody Gray Great answer. I've found this to be very helpful with my learning process. I'm currently doing static analysis of Windows malware, but I am a complete newb to Windows. I've spent the last couple of hours trying to find something like a release-notes page for Microsoft Linker.
Can someone verify that Microsoft Linker (9.0) was released in 2008 ?